# load one page into another page

Tags: jquery, html

i have used below code to load one page into another

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a id="work" href="">Work</a></li>
        <li><a id="profile" href="">Profile</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="container"></div>
<script>
    $("#work").click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#container").load("work.html");
    }
    $("#profile").click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#container").load("profile.html");
    }
</script>

</body>
```

in the loaded page i want to load 3rd page but same script is not working for 3rd page

work.html

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
    <button id="btn">Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        $("#btn").click(function(){
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#container").load("thirdpage.html");
        }
    </scirpt>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried for the third page?

Comment: What that mean by 3rd page?

Comment: What errors do you get in the console? And btw, `</scirpt>`

Answer (score 0):

If you've copied your code verbatim, work.html contains a typo on your closing script tag: `</scirpt>`.

Change it to `</script>` and you'll be fine.